# How to resolve linker error in RUST Cross compilation

Tags: rust, cross-compiling

I am trying to achieve cross compilation in rust to the raspberry pi. However there was a linkage error while compiler:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
```

However for resolving that I have to download new linker and not use the default.
While doing so I checked the information of my raspberry system by using:

```
rustup show
```

Got the following result:

```
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/akumar/.rustup

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.64.0 (a55dd71d5 2022-09-19)
```

Now for resolving the issue I have to download the package using the following command:

```
sudo apt install gcc-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

but after running the command, I am getting the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
```

Comment: Where are you compiling? In the host or in the target? If you compiling in the host you can try compile directly on your raspberry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:
`sudo apt install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf`
for build your rust project:
`cargo build --target=armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`

Please check tool - cross: https://github.com/cross-rs/cross
Cross uses docker for build and makes libraries isolation.

Comment: Thank you ! I found out for tool chain 'gcc-armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf' we can use linker - gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf .